# When I run localhost/phpmyadmin then I got some code

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2

First of all sorry and I know this is the duplicate question. I tried all most all the things to fix this issue but none of them works for me.

**Issue** 
[image: Issue]

Tried:

1) Run commands which I got while search issue. 
2) Uninstall apache2 and phpmyadmin and re-install them again. 
3) Uninstall php and install php again. 
4) Download the adminer.php file and try to run but still getting some php code.

Comment: So basically _no_ PHP script “works”, _any_ script would just show you the code? Well then you apparently don’t have PHP properly integrated with your web server …

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: PHP 7.2 version

Comment: @CBroe What can I do next?

Comment: Google a proper tutorial how to set up Apache & PHP? If you can’t manage to get it configured & running properly, use a package like XAMP/MAMP instead?

Comment: I have also installed that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same problem and I fixed this way.

1) Uninstall XAMPP.

2) Install XAMPP.

Is you face a same issue again then try to re-install `php`m `apache2`, `XAMPP`.